# Filling up values in a column in data stage

Tags: datastage

How can i add values in the fields of a column dynamically? I have a column called email and i want to make corresponding email indicator column fields as 'Y' or 'N' if email is present or not respectively.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a transformer - it should be a simple logic (derivation) like

```
IF len(to_tx.EMAIL) > 0 then 'Y' ELSE 'N'
```